# Need help in Python printing a blank field for incorrect values from a made up contacts list

Tags: python, arrays, list

I need help figuring out how to print a blank field for the incorrect values within a contacts list (Hardwired in). Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve.

```
[In] contacts = [['Mike Green',   '21873', '5555555555'],
                ['Sage', '57105', '605414147']]

Currently printing:
[Out]               Name        Zip         Phone
0             Mike Green      21873  555-555-5555
1                   Sage      57105     605414147

Needing it to print this instead:
[Out]               Name        Zip         Phone
0             Mike Green      21873  555-555-5555
1                   Sage      57105
```

Here is my code and what I currently have typed out:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

contacts = [['Mike Green',   '21873', '5555555555'],
           ['Donette Foller', '45011', '5135701893'],
           ['Mitsue Tollner', '60632', '7735736914'],
           ['Leota Dilliard', '95111', '4087523500'],
           ['Sage', '57105', '605414147'],
           ['Helen Cooper', 'asxa23245', '3421322323'],
           ['Jim Roberts90on', '21801', '5555555555'],
           ['J324osephine Darakjy', '48116', '8103749840'],
           ['Venere', '08014', '8562644130'],
           ['Lenna Paprocki', '99501', '9073854412'],
           ['Donette Foller', '45011', '5135701893'],
           ['Simona Morasca', '44805', '4195032484'],
           ['Mitsue', '60632', '7735736914'],
           ['Leota Dilliard', '95111', '4087523500'],
           ['Sage Wieser', '57105', '6054142147'],
           ['Helen Cooper', '23245', '3421222323'],
           ['Robertson', 'ssasx-21', '5555555555'],
           ['Josephine Darakjy', '48116', '8103749840'],
           ['Art Venere', '', '2644130'],
           ['Paprocki', '99501', '9073854412']]

  contactsdf = pd.DataFrame(contacts,columns=['Name', 'Zip', 'Phone'])

  def get_formatted_phone(value):
      result = re.fullmatch(r'(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})',   value)
      return '-'.join(result.groups()) if   result else value

  formatted_phone = contactsdf['Phone'].map(get_formatted_phone)
  contactsdf['Phone'] =   formatted_phone

  print(contactsdf)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a blank field then simply change the value in your get_formatted_phone function to this:

```
def get_formatted_phone(value):
    result = re.fullmatch(r'(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})',   value)
    return '-'.join(result.groups()) if   result else ''
```

To format the Zip codes in a similar way, assuming the correct values will always be 5 characters long and the incorrect ones will not you could use the following:

```
def get_formatted_zip(value):
    return value if len(value) == 5 else ''
contactsdf['Zip'] = contactsdf['Zip'].map(get_formatted_zip)
```

If the incorrect Zip values are not so easily spotted then you could use something like this:

```
def get_formatted_zip(value):
    try:
        if len(str(int(value))) == 5:
            return value
        else:
            return ''
    except:
        return ''
```

Comment: I totally looked over that, Thank you! Would you have an idea of how to get the Zip codes to show only 5 digit numbers? If other than 5 digit numbers it would be blank? I kind of have an idea but do not know exactly how to go about this in python.

Comment: I’ll edit my answer to add this but it depends on the possible format of the incorrect values. All the zip codes are stored as strings so you can’t just use a type() argument. Just use the simplest solution above that fits with any potential incorrect values...

Comment: When I tried the given code earlier for the phone numbers, my code worked and displayed blanks for the incorrect numbers. But once I turn my pc off for an update and came back to edit my code and add the zip code line, I get an error saying "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object" starting with: formatted_phone = contactsdf['Phone'].map(get_formatted_phone) throwing up the first error in the list

Comment: That’s odd... Are the contacts just stored in the list or is there another source that could have changed or moved since the update? If the contacts list is in another Jupiter notebook cell, for instance then when the server is restarted you would need to run that cell for it to be loaded into the memory... just a thought...

Comment: I went back and removed some of the contacts from the list and found that when I pass 18 contacts in the list, it gives me the error. When I stay within 18 or below, the list prints. Could this be a limit with memory within the code?? Other than that, everything works fine now. Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: Where are running your code? And what is the 18th entry that is causing the error? This should be an issue for even the smallest amount of pc memory but I’ll wager that if you edit your get_formatted_phone function to match the get_formatted_zip function with a try: ... except: ... clause in it then this won’t be a problem. Cheers

Comment: Thats exactly what I did. I found out the issue when troubleshooting with a friend of mine. Thank you so much for your help =D